# x64 Windows 8 Pro Metro IE 10

Tags: windows-8, 32-bit, modern-ui, internet-explorer-10

In an x64 architecture of Windows 8, is it possible to run the Metro IE 10 application in 32 bit mode? I know it is possible in the desktop version of IE, but I am wondering if it is possible in the Metro-style app?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what difference does it make? There's some significance for the desktop version because plugins are typically 32-bit. But AFAIK the metro version disallows plugins.

Comment: It matters because there are certain applications (such as plugins, web apps, etc) that are only supported in 32 bit version of IE. If it is possible to run the metro-style IE in 32 bit mode, I would like to know to how to do this to see if support can be claimed for an application (custom built) running in metro style IE 32 bit (under 64 bit windows 8).

Comment: If you want a 32-bit version of the Modern UI IE10 that would require a 32-bit installation of Windows 8.  Its unlikely you will be able to use the metro ie10 engine within an application.

Answer (score 3):

The "modern" version of IE 10 on Windows 8 is 64 bit only. Please see the following MSDN article that details 64 bit along with why dealing with EPM (Enhanced Protection Mode)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Going by the comments above, this seems to be the actual reason for the question:

> It matters because there are certain applications (such as plugins, web apps, etc) that are only supported in 32 bit version of IE. If it is possible to run the metro-style IE in 32 bit mode, I would like to know to how to do this to see if support can be claimed for an application (custom built) running in metro style IE 32 bit (under 64 bit windows 8).

Even if Metro IE did run in 32-bit mode, you *still* wouldn't get what you want if it is plugin support you're after. Why? Because Metro IE is plugin-free, as detailed by this article: [Get ready for plug-in free browsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Other than Flash which is a built-in component and uses a regularly updated CV blacklist (it used to rely on a whitelist earlier), no other plugin is allowed access to Metro IE.

As for pure JS web apps, there's nothing that would prevent them from running in 64-bit IE, Metro or Desktop version.

Comment: I wish I had more upvotes to give.